# How can I use class instance statically?

Tags: python

```
import logging

class Logger:

    @staticmethod
    def set(log_module_name, log_level):
        Log = logging.getLogger(log_module_name)
        Log.setLevel(log_level)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname).1s %(message)s',
            "%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        Log.addHandler(stream_handler)
        
    @staticmethod
    def debug(msg):
        Log.debug(msg)
```

I want to use like this:

```
    Logger.debug("test message")
```

But I got errors:

```
  File "myfunc.py", line 113, in debug
    Log.debug(msg)
NameError: name 'Log' is not defined
```

How can I use Log as statically?

Comment: Log currently only exists inside set. Maybe they _shouldn't_ be static methods?

Comment: Why do you want those as static methods?

Comment: I want to make my own custom log function.

Comment: just use instance methods and make it `self.log` instead of `Log` (which is only local to the method you define it in)

Comment: The `logging` module has a facility to get the loggers objects present in logging tree: `getLogger()`. There's usually no need to write own Logger classes or have extra mechanisms to get the right logger. See the [logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for details!

Answer (score 0):

My colleague solved my problem. Simply adding global solved my question. T.T

```
import logging

class Logger:

    @staticmethod
    def set(log_module_name, log_level):

        global Log

        Log = logging.getLogger(log_module_name)
        Log.setLevel(log_level)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname).1s %(message)s',
            "%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    .....
```